# How to use buildOpticalFlowPyramid?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 3.3.1. I want to do a semi-dense optical flow operation using `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, but I've been getting some really noticeable slowdown whenever my ROI is pretty big (*Partly due to the fact that I am letting the user decide what the winSize should be, ranging from from 10 to 100*). Anyways, it seems like `cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid` can mitigate the slowdown by building image pyramids? I'm sorta familiar what image pyramids are, but in context of the function, I'm especially confused about what parameters I pass in, and how it impacts my function call to `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. With that in mind, I now have these set of questions:

- The output is, according to the documentation, is an `OutputArrayOfArrays`, which I take it can be a vector of cv::Mat objects. If so, what do I pass in to `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` for `prevImg` and `nextImg` (*assuming that I need to make image pyramids for both*)?
- According to the docs for `cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid`, you need to pass in a winSize parameter in order to calculate required padding for pyramid levels. If so, do you pass in the same winSize value when you eventually call `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`?
- What exactly are the arguments for `pyrBorder` and `derivBorder` doing?
- Lastly, and apologies if it sounds newbish, but what is the purpose of this function? I always assumed that `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` internally builds the image pyramids. Is it just to speed up the optical flow operation?

I hope my questions were clear, I'm still very new to OpenCV, and computer vision, but this topic is very interesting.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

I used the function to see if my guess was correct, so far it has worked, but I've seen no noticeable speed up. Below is how I used it:

```
    // Building pyramids
    int maxLvl = 3;
    maxLvl = cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(imgPrev, imPyr1, cv::Size(searchSize, searchSize), maxLvl, true);
    maxLvl = cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(tmpImg, imPyr2, cv::Size(searchSize, searchSize), maxLvl, true);

    // LK optical flow call
    cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(imPyr1, imPyr2, currentPoints, nextPts, status, err,
                             cv::Size(searchSize, searchSize), maxLvl, termCrit, 0, 0.00001);
```

So now I'm wondering what's the purpose of preparing the image pyramids if calcOpticalFlowPyrLK does it internally?

Comment: In your case a precomputed image pyramid wount accelerate your code much. Building the pyramid internally takes aprox. 20 millisecond. The slow down when inreasing winSize has nothing with the image pyramids used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the point of your question is that you are trying to improve speed of optical flow tracking by tuning your input parameters.

If you want dirty and quick answer then here it is

```
 KTL (OpenCV's calcOpticalFlowPyrLK) define a e residual function which are sum of gradient of point inside search window .
The main purpose is to find vector of point that can minimize residual function
So if you increase search window size (winSize) then it is more difficult to find that set of points.
```

If your really really want to do that then please read the official paper. 
See the section 2.4

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.185.585&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I took it from official document

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#bouguet00

Hope that help